Efficiently Finding Nearest Locations from Large Datasets in Python
I am working on a project where I need to find the three nearest geographical locations (from a dataset of 1,000 entries) for each entry in another large dataset consisting of 500,000 addresses. Each dataset includes latitude and longitude coordinates. I've been using Python with geopy and pandas, but due to the size of the datasets I am not sure what could be the best approach.
Here is a simplified version of my code (reproducible):
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic

# Sample data setup
data = {
    "Zip Code": ["10115", "20095", "50667", "80331", "70173", "40210", "41460", "45127", "47051", "40474"],
    "City": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Cologne", "Munich", "Stuttgart", "Düsseldorf", "Neuss", "Essen", "Duisburg", "Düsseldorf Airport"],
    "Latitude": [52.5323, 53.5503, 50.9367, 48.1372, 48.7833, 51.2217, 51.1981, 51.4556, 51.4344, 51.2895],
    "Longitude": [13.3846, 9.9930, 6.9540, 11.5755, 9.1815, 6.7763, 6.6913, 7.0116, 6.7623, 6.7668]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_df2 = {
    "Address": ["my_location"],
    "ZipCode": ["40468"],
    "Latitude": [51.28472232436951],
    "Longitude": [6.7865234073914005]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df2)

# Distance calculation
def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    return geodesic((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)).kilometers

def find_nearest_spots(address_lat, address_lon):
    distances = df.apply(lambda row: calculate_distance(address_lat, address_lon, row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']), axis=1)
    nearest_indices = distances.nsmallest(3).index
    nearest_spots = df.loc[nearest_indices]
    return pd.Series({
        'Nearest_1_Spot': nearest_spots.iloc[0]['City'],
        'Nearest_1_Dist': distances.iloc[nearest_indices[0]],
        'Nearest_2_Spot': nearest_spots.iloc[1]['City'],
        'Nearest_2_Dist': distances.iloc[nearest_indices[1]],
        'Nearest_3_Spot': nearest_spots.iloc[2]['City'],
        'Nearest_3_Dist': distances.iloc[nearest_indices[2]]
    })

df2[['Nearest_1_Spot', 'Nearest_1_Dist', 'Nearest_2_Spot', 'Nearest_2_Dist', 'Nearest_3_Spot', 'Nearest_3_Dist']] = df2.apply(
    lambda row: find_nearest_spots(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']), axis=1)


if needed I can also leverage free GPU libraries (if any)
Thanks for guidance

How urgently do you need to find neighbours with respect to geodesic distances? Is a simple "3 nearest lon/lat" also sufficient?

@raphael should be fine I guess, because then I can simply join the df2 to get the address & city etc - The most pressing issue is that I have 1000 vs 500000 lat long values  - means these many PnC calculations. my heart says there must be a solution for this
for example if point a is in duesseldorf germany, then I should not find distances for points which are in other states or countries, hope you understand what I mean. Thanks

In my opinion a KDTree should do the job just fine in a fraction of a second for 500k points...

@raphael oh, wow, could you please help me with the code on my test dataset? Thank you in advance

I've created a very quick example (with numpy arrays....) it should give you the building blocks you need!

As mentioned in the comment, I'd suggest using a KDtree to identify nearest neighbours.
Here's a quick example how you can query 3 nearest neighbours of 1000 points from a list of 500k points:
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import numpy as np

# setup a search-tree for locations
lons, lats = np.random.normal(0, 50, 500000), np.random.normal(0, 50, 500000)
tree = KDTree(np.column_stack([lons, lats]))

# query points
q_lons, q_lats = np.random.normal(0, 50, 1000), np.random.normal(0, 50, 1000)
dist, idx = tree.query(np.column_stack([q_lons, q_lats]), k=3, distance_upper_bound=1)

# get mask for points without valid neighbours
mask = idx == tree.n

# extract neighbour coordinates 
# (use "warp" because points representing invalid neighbours are indicated with a too large index value)
neighbour_lons = np.take(lons, idx, mode="warp")
neighbour_lons[mask] = np.nan
neighbour_lats = np.take(lats, idx, mode="warp")
neighbour_lats[mask] = np.nan

Plot results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# to color points
c = q_lons**2 + q_lats**2
c = plt.cm.tab20(c/c.max())

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(lons, lats, c="k", s=5)
ax.scatter(q_lons, q_lats, marker="o", s=70, c=c)
ax.scatter(neighbour_lons.ravel(), neighbour_lats.ravel(), 
           marker="x", s=70, c=c.repeat(3, axis=0))


